# Cannot GET error while trying to access URL using module.export (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I'm getting **`"Cannot GET /speakers"`** error on my browser when I am trying to access http://localhost:3000/speakers from the following code:

**My Server.js File**

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')

const routes = require('./routes')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.set('view engine','ejs')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'./views'))

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'./static')))
app.use('/', routes())

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`Express server listening on port ${port}!`)
})
```

**My Script.js File**
This is my server.js file where I've declared various variables

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

module.exports = () =>{
    router.get('/',(request, response) =>{
        return response.send('Speakers List')
    })

    router.get('/:shortname',(request, response) =>{
        return response.send(`Detail page of {request.params.shortname}`)
    })

    return router;
}
```

**My index.js file**

```
const express = require('express')

const speakersRoute = require('./speakers')
const feedbackRoute = require('./feedback')

const router = express.Router()

module.exports = () =>{
    router.get('/',(request, response) =>{
        response.render('pages/index',{ pageTitle: 'Welcome'})
    })

    router.use('./speakers', speakersRoute())
    router.use('./feedback', feedbackRoute())
    return router
}
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Is it your whole code ? Where is your server.js, where do you import the router ?

Comment: Where did you define your speaker file? All I see is My Script.js

Comment: @BENARDPatrick Updated server.js

Comment: @F.Frlić inside index.js file..

Comment: try GET at /speakers/ <- notice the second slash?

Comment: @LoveenDyall tried it.. it throws an error !!

Comment: Your call back in `router.use('./speakers', speakersRoute())` shouldn't be a router instance, only app takes a router instance in `app.use()`. you need to pass a callback function as the second argument.
see https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.use

Comment: @LoveenDyall I went through your reference. So what's the solution for my code? :))

Answer (score 1):

Have you try change './speaker' to '/speaker' ?

```
// router.use('./speakers', speakersRoute())
router.use('/speakers', speakersRoute())
```